# Responsividade Css

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) and (min-width: 600px) {
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200%;
    }


    body {
        background: #f8f8f8;
        font-family: "Verdana", Times, serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 10px;
        height: 100%;

    }


    #usuario {
        font-size: 11px;

    }

    .menu ul {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }


    .footer {
        height: 10%;
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .webGrid {
        margin: 11px;
        margin-left: 25px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 40%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 10.1px;
        float: left;
    }

    .webGrid2 {
        margin: 10px;
        margin-left: 400px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 35%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-top: 900px;
    }

    .headerGrid a {
        color: rgb(00, 87, 147);
        text-decoration: none;


    }

    .comentario {
        max-width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;


    }

    .grafico {
        float: left;

    }



    #chartContainer, #chartContainer2 {
        zoom: 52%;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-top: 400px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1%;

    }

    #chartContainer3, #chartContainer4 {
        zoom: 52%;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-top: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-top: 10.5%

    }

    #chartContainer5 {
        zoom: 50%;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-top: 416px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1%;

    }


}
```

ao redimensionar a tela todo conteúdo se redimensiona, nos gráficos dei um zoom, para que o gráfico fique com um tamanho em evidencia a pedido do usuário, o problema é que os nomes e que estão em cima dos gráficos não aumentam conforme o zoom que eu coloquei, como posso configurar para que fique de uma forma proporcional?

Comment: Mas se vc quer aumentar pq colocou o Zoom em 50%? Deveria por em 150%

Comment: @hugocsl 50% atende oque foi pedido por eles,antes eu havia colocado 150%

Comment: Esses gráficos estão sendo feito via plugin? como eles estão sendo construídos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que declarar o `font-size` em cada `@media-screen` para ficar realmente como você quer. Dê uma lida [aqui](https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/tipografia-responsiva.php), isso também vai ajudar.

Comment: eu fiz isso e mesmo assim o que está escrito em cima do gráfico não correspondeu ,a fonte continua do mesmo tamanho, coloquei um print pra tentar deixar mais claro.

Comment: tenta colocar  '!important' no 'font-size'

Comment: e limpa o cache do navegador